# Composition of equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

As part of a HW assignment in the course elementary set theory, I was given the following question:

> Let $A$ be a set and let $T$ and $S$ be two equivalence relations on $A$.
>
> Prove: $S\circ T=T\circ S \iff S\circ T$ is an equivalence relation
>
> The $\Longleftarrow $ direction was not so difficult but I had a problem
> with the $\Longrightarrow $ direction.

I managed to prove reflexiveness and symmetry of $S\circ T$, but cannot prove the transitivity of $S\circ T$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relation $R$ is transitive iff $R \circ R \subseteq R$.

So we need to prove $(S\circ T)\circ(S\circ T) \subseteq S \circ T$. Note that the brackets are optional -- composition of relations is associative.

Can you see how the assumption $S \circ T = T \circ S$ helps us here? (Remember that $S$ and $T$ are also equivalence relations.)

Comment: do you mean that i need to prove: $(S\circ T)\circ (S\circ T)\subseteq S\circ T$ ?

if the answer is yes then how can i do this? thanks

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have edited with a further hint.

Comment: well, i still missing something. if i understand correctly then i need to show that $(S\circ T)\circ (S\circ T)=(S\circ T)\circ (T\circ S)=S\circ (T\circ T)\circ S\subseteq S\circ T$ 

and i know also that $S$ and $T$ are equivalence relations so i also know that $T\circ T\subseteq T$  and  $S\circ S\subseteq S$
but im stil stuck

Comment: Final hint: Note that $(S \circ T)\circ(S \circ T) = S \circ (T \circ S) \circ T$. I'm confident you can do it from here.

Comment: oh, right i used the $S\circ T=T\circ S$ on the wrong pair.
thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :). Note that you could also have applied the assumption to your result $S \circ (T \circ S)$, so it was not exactly "wrong" :).