# Prove if relation $R$ on set $A$ is a relation equivalence then also $R^{2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

My attempt:

- $R \circ R = R^{2}$

**Proving reflexively:** since $R$ is symmetrical then $aRb$ and $bRa$ so $R^{2}$ will be $aR^{2}a$

**Proving symmetrical:** since $R$ is transitive $aRb ,bRc = aRc$ also $R$ is symmetric so
$bRa,cRb = cRa$

$aRc\circ bRa = bR^{2}c$

$cRa \circ aRb = cR^{2}b $

I don't know how to prove $R^{2}$ is transitive also is my method for proving reflexive and symmetric correct?

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254016/composition-of-equivalence-relations?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The reflexive property of $R^2$ comes from the very same reflexive property of $R$, since when using the symmetrical property of $R$ you had to assume that such $b$ existed for $a$ in the first place, and the only $b$ that's guaranteed to exist is $a$ itself. So there's no need of the symmetrical property.

For the symmetrical property of $R^2$ I'm not sure about the meaning of what you wrote. You have to show that if $aR^2b$ then $bR^2a$. The $aR^2b$ it's the starting point, not part of the proof. Maybe I'm just a little confused. Hint for this part: Use the definition of $R^2$ for $aR^2b$ and then use the symmetrical property of $R$.

Lastly, for the transitive property of $R^2$ you just have to use the definition of $R^2$ for both $aR^2b$ and $bR^2c$ and then use the transitive property of $R$ to get $aR^2c$.