# Symmetricity of composition of equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I stumbled upon this question:

> Let $A$ be a set and $T$ and $S$ two equivalence relations on $A$.
>
> Prove: $S\circ T=T\circ S \iff S\circ T$ is an equivalence relation

In these questions

[equivalence relation composition problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600978/equivalence-relation-composition-problem)

[Composition of equivalence relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254016/composition-of-equivalence-relations)

the OPs asked for the proof of transitivity of composition of equivalence relations.

My question is how to prove the symmetricity?

If we assume $(x,y) \in ST $, we need to prove $(y,x) \in ST$.

By definition,  there exists $h$ such that $(x,h) \in T$ and $(h,y) \in S$.

Getting anywhere from there seems to be a mystery for me.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: edited, should be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sequel $R^{\text{op}}:=\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid\langle y,x\rangle\in R\}$ for any relation $R$.

If $S$ and $T$ are both symmetric then actually we have:$$S^{\text{op}}=S\text{ and }T^{\text{op}}=T$$

Then consequently:$$\left(S\circ T\right)^{\text{op}}=T^{\text{op}}\circ S^{\text{op}}=T\circ S$$

Now if we also have $T\circ S=S\circ T$  then this results in:$$\left(S\circ T\right)^{\text{op}}=S\circ T$$
This states exactly that $S\circ T$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question: what does $\wedge$ mean?

Comment: It stands for "and".

Comment: Oh, of course. For some reason, I thought it was some kind of operation on sets. Thanks once again.

Comment: You are welcome. The notation is indeed a bit tricky here, so I changed it.