# Equivalence in relations over the same set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are equivalence relations over the same set $X.$ Prove or disprove
whether $B \circ A$ is an equivalence relation.

For the sake of proving or disproving this statement I will use set $X = \{1,2,3\}.$
So that would mean if I'm not mistaken the equivalence of the sets would be..

$A = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,1)\}$

$B = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,3),(3,1)\}$

How would i go about disproving or proving $B \circ A$????

Comment: The equivalence of a set is a meaningless term.  As $B \circ A$ is a realation, it cannot be proved.  To prove something, it has to be a statement.

Comment: You cannot prove this statement in general by choosing one example, only disprove it by means of a counterexample. Also, it appears that this is only true if $A$ and $B$ commute, i.e. $A\circ B=B\circ A$. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600978/equivalence-relation-composition-problem